# How to format date in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, python-2.x

I made a crawler using python.

But my crawler get date in this format:

```
s = page_ad.findAll('script')[25].text.replace('\'', '"')
s = re.search(r'\{.+\}', s, re.DOTALL).group() # get json data
s = re.sub(r'//.+\n', '', s) # replace comment
s = re.sub(r'\s+', '', s) # strip whitspace
s = re.sub(r',}', '}', s) # get rid of last , in the dict
dataLayer = json.loads(s)
print dataLayer["page"]["adDetail"]["adDate"]

2017-01-1412:28:07
```

I want only date without hours (`2017-01-14`), how get only date if not have white spaces?

Comment: You should provide a [mcve]. As it stands nobody has any clue what you're actually doing to get that date.

Comment: Slice the end off: `date[:10]`

Answer (score 1):

use string subset:

```
>>> date ="2017-01-1412:28:07"

>>> datestr= date[:-8]
>>> datestr
'2017-01-14'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
In [2]: from datetime import datetime

In [3]: now = datetime.now()

In [4]: now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
Out[4]: '2017-01-24'
```

### Update

I suggest you parse the date first into `datetime` object and then show the relevant information out of it.

for this a better approach would be using a library for this.
I use [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for this tasks, example usage:

```
import dateparser
date = dateparser.parse('12/12/12')
date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is not a standard date format, just slice the end.

```
st = "2017-01-1412:28:07"
res = st[:10]
print res

>>>2017-01-14
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `datetime` as follows to first convert it into a datetime object, and then format the output as required using the [`stftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=strptime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) function:

```
from datetime import datetime

ad_date = dataLayer["page"]["adDetail"]["adDate"]
print datetime.strptime(ad_date, "%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

This will print:

```
2017-01-14
```

By using this method, it would give you the flexibility to display other items, for example adding `%A` to the end would give you the day of the week:

```
print datetime.strptime(ad_date, "%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %A")
```

e.g.

```
2017-01-14 Saturday
```